# aws s3 not able to delete the object by code php

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am putting a object in my AWS S3 basket by using following code.

```
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $_FILES["file"]["name"] = $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);

        $filepath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        try {
            $result = $this->Amazon->S3->putObject(array(
                'Bucket' => 'mytest.sample',
                'ACL' => 'authenticated-read',
                'Key' => 'files/image/' . $id . '/' . $newfilename,
                'ServerSideEncryption' => 'aws:kms',
                'SourceFile' => $filepath,
                'ContentType' => mime_content_type($filepath),

            ));
        } catch (S3Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
```

and it is working fine. files are uploading but when I try to delete the file empty response I am getting.
here is the code used for deleting object.

```
try {
                $result = $this->Amazon->S3->deleteMatchingObjects(array(
                    'Bucket' => 'mytest.sample',
                    //'Key' => 'files/image/' . $id . '/' . $fileName['Attachment']['attachment'],
                    'Key' => 'files/image/45/1441026402.docx', //static path for checking.
                    'VersionId' => 'latest',
                ));
            } catch (S3Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            }
```

I tried below method too

```
   try {
        $result = $this->Amazon->S3->deleteObject(array(
            'Bucket' => 'mytest.sample',
            //'Key' => 'files/image/' . $id . '/' . $fileName['Attachment']['attachment'],
            'Key' => 'files/image/45/1441026402.docx',
            'VersionId' => 'latest',
        ));
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

[image]

> Is there any permission issue?

Comment: Is an exception being thrown? if so, what's the message? Have you tried `var_dump($result)` to see if there's a success/fail?

Comment: I am getting empty response. and there is no exception I am getting.

Comment: Consider enabling logging: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html - then check to see if perhaps there's something wrong with the request.

Comment: many log file in `var/log` folder . which file I should check?
latest updated files are `auth.log` and `syslog`

Comment: Check all with latest time stamps.

Comment: didn't find anything relative..